# Override springboot JPARepository default timezone

Tags: java, spring

Since upgrading to springboot 3.x writes to mysql database are done in UTC (previously it used jvm setting). Is there  a way to override this back to JVM.

I have tried using

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = Europe/Stockholm
spring.jackson.time-zone= Europe/Stockholm
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${block.db.host}:${block.db.port}/${block.db.name}?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&**serverTimezone=Europe/Stockholm
```

**
but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The timezone behavior changes doesnt come from spring-boot per-se. It stems from the mysql-connector (which's version is defined by spring-boot). I guess you updated beyond [mysql-connector 8.0.23](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-23.html) which changed that behavior. Their release notes state:

> Important Change: A new mechanism has been introduced for users to configure how time zone conversions should occur when time instants are saved to or retrieved from a server by Connector/J. Three new connection properties, preserveInstants, connectionTimeZone, and forceConnectionTimeZoneToSession, control the new mechanism—see Preserving Time Instants for details.

> Important To preserve the default behavior of Connector/J 8.0.22 and earlier to query the session time zone from the server and then convert a timestamp between that and the JVM time zone, set the new connection property connectionTimeZone to SERVER, and leave the other two new properties at their default values (i.e.,preserveInstants=true and forceConnectionTimeZoneToSession=false). Users who had serverTimeZone=user-defined-time-zone and keep it the same, without configuring the new connection properties, can expect the same behavior as before, but testing is recommended.
> Also, with the implementation of the new mechanism, a getObject(columnIndex) call on a DATETIME column returns a LocalDateTime object now instead of a String. To receive a String like before, use getObject(columnIndex, String.class) instead.

Comment: I tried updating the connectionstring with the information above but it made no difference
Tried
jdbc:mysql://${block.db.host}:${block.db.port}/${block.db.name}?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Stockholm&preserveInstant=true&connectionTimeZone=Europe/Stockholm&forceConnectionTimeZoneToSession=false

and combinations of removing other properties.

Comment: Update your code. Show us an example of a timezone in your database. If the date object contains timezone information, it is not wrong per-se.